# How to import and export multiple data using sas macro?

Tags: import, dataset, export, sas

Hi I am trying to do a macro in sas to the following function

I have multiple sas files(apr12part1, apr12part2,...,aug12part1,aug12part2), for each file(for example:apr12part1) , I will do some process which will give me three output(for example: apr12part1out1,apr12part1out2,pr12part1out3).

I was trying to use macro, but was not very sucssesful. Can someone help me with it? Thank you very much!
The code I was using is something like this

```
%macro test(month=,part=);
   ...FROM EC100002.&month_part_&part
   ...
   proc export data=SASUSER.Out1 outfile='G:\Output\Output1_&month_&part.csv' dbms=csv replace;
   proc export data=SASUSER.Out2 outfile='G:\Output\Output2_&month_&part.csv' dbms=csv replace;
   proc export data=SASUSER.Out3 outfile='G:\Output\Output3_&month_&part.csv' dbms=csv replace;
   run;
%mend test
```

%test(month=apr12,part=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding "dots" to concatenate the macro variables into a complete string.  Also, you must use double-quotes, not single-quotes.  Something like this:

```
proc export data=SASUSER.Out1 
     outfile="G:\Output\Output1_&month._&part..csv" dbms=csv replace;
```

Note there are two "dots" after your `&part` variable; the first is a concatenation operator and the second is part of the file name.

You probably have similar issues with the code not displayed, so check that as well.

Comment: Thank you! I tried your method but the log gave me some error and couldn't finish the run WARNING: The quoted string currently being processed has become more than 262 characters long.  
         You may have unbalanced quotation marks.

Comment: Well, that message means you have a stray single or double quote somewhere in your program.  If you are doing this interactively, your session is likely messed up. You can try clearing it by submitting this code:  `*'; *"; *); */; %mend; run;` (known as the SAS "magic string").

Comment: I'm thinking does the &month inside the quotation mark matters?   Is this validate in SAS?

Comment: Where should I put the code? At the bottom in the macro right before the %mend? then Do I need another %mend?

Comment: No, that code should not be part of any program.  It is just something you "submit" manually whenever you get a WARNING message like that.  It might be better for you to save your programming code and restart your SAS session.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Please "accept" the answer so it get marked as "answered".  And welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: The period is not a concatenation operators. Instead it is an indication to the macro processor where the name of the macro variable ends.  So they are part of the reference to the macro variable.